# Convert =00 formatted UTF codes in a plain text file to the correct utf character in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encoding, hex, character, utf-32

writing a simple program to extract all the postal addresses from a big plain text file, having a problem as some of the addresses use non-standard characters.

This is some source text from the file I need to process:

Rua Vale de Louro, N=BA 97
Bloco 2, 1=BA A

but it needs to read:

Rua Vale de Louro, Nº 97
Bloco 2, 1º A

now obviously i could do a simple replace for this one characters but I need it to work with every character.

BA is the hex value of the º symbol in utf32 (albeit with a load of zeros preceding it) so if I can code something to find all these "=xx" instances in the string and replace them with the correct utf character that would solve it. but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Can Anyone Help?

Thanks

Comment: Believing in "plain text" ⇒ [Programming by Coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence).

Comment: Two encodings are used here.  Original text was, probably, using the Windows 1252 code page, then got converted by a quoted-printable encoder.  Send it back, you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Dim txt As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("fileName", System.Text.Encoding.encoding) 'ASCII, UFT32, UFT8, Unicode etc...
```

Change the word *encoding* with the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using regular expressions with a match evaluator to calculate the replacement string.

```
Dim input = "Rua Vale de Louro, N=BA 97 Bloco 2, 1=BA A"
Dim expected = "Rua Vale de Louro, Nº 97 Bloco 2, 1º A"

Dim regex = new Regex("=([0-9A-Fa-f]+)",RegexOptions.CultureInvariant, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))          
Dim evaluator = Function(match)  Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups(1).Value, 16))

Dim actual = regex.Replace(input, evaluator)
```

The pattern matches = followed by one or more hex digits. The hex digits are in group 1.

The evaluator takes the hex digits, converts to an integer from base 16 and then converts to a Unicode codepoint.